# npm install on VueJS

Tags: vue.js, npm-install

I am trying to install [this](https://www.creative-tim.com/learning-lab/tailwind/vue/quick-start/notus) script. I am trying to run `npm install` command. But this is not working. This is stuck after message `idealTree:color-convert: timing idealTree:node_modules/c`.

[image]

Could anyone help me to install this script ?

Comment: Delete your node-modules and package-lock, and run `npm install` again

Comment: Thanks @DonaldShahini. There is no `node-modules` and `package-lock` in my project folder.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxlq4.png

Comment: Try `npm cache clean`, maybe it helps. If it does not, then try `DEBUG=* npm install` to see more about the error.

Comment: Thanks @DonaldShahini. Result of `DEBUG=* npm install` is like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A6P2.png

Comment: Try `npm install --verbose`, hopefully it will give a better error description. Are you using windows, mac or linux? It can be a proxy problem, but I am not so sure

Answer (score 1):

I tried it myself and had the same issue.

There might be an issue on the author's end or with some dependency.
Try contacting the author of the package to investigate the issue.

You can create an issue here: https://github.com/creativetimofficial/vue-notus/issues

Answer (score 1):

nice you can delete your node modules and try again...

or you can try `npm cache clean`

if both fails you can try yarn...

Comment: Thanks @Gift . There is no `node modules`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxlq4.png